# Fix broken display settings - persistent LiveUSB

Tags: 16.04, live-usb, macbook-pro, persistence

I have been running my MacBook off a persistent live USB using Ubuntu 16.04.

For another problem I'm having, it was suggested I start up holding down c.

My display settings seemed to not be the correct ones anymore.

I'll get a black screen.

It used to intermittently flash a wrong display settings pop-up window on the black screen when I move my mouse.

I told it to go back to my log on screen using that window and it is now always a black screen.

Is there a way for me to fix the display settings in this persistent live USB?

Comment: Will your computer boot from the USB drive, when you boot it without persistence (when you remove the boot option `persistent`?

Comment: Yes. It seems to boot fine, except that if I've tried to boot it persistence recently, I have to detach and reattach the USB before restarting the computer

Comment: Can you remember or imagine what you did or what happened just before the screen went black (when running persistent live)?

Comment: If you cannot fix the problem, you can keep the home partition and re-install the programs the you had installed.

Comment: I booted into persistence while holding down c. Large amounts of white text on a black background when scrolling past, instead of the smallest amounts of white text on a black background

Comment: I hope to not have to redo the USB, because on a Mac it requires some extra steps and I'll have to figure out which programs I wanted

Comment: I have no own experience of MacBooks, but I have a lot of experience of persistent live systems. I don't know what it means to boot while holding down c, but I would be very surprised if it modifies the operating system.

Comment: It was weird I can tell you that

Comment: So, when I was booting the live USB, I had to type 2 1 5 0 on the screens before it boots. After typing 0, which I know you know has the system finally boot up, I held down C. Then the scrolling text, then the , then the not being able to use the computer

Comment: How did you shutdown or reboot the computer, when it had a black screen? Maybe that action caused a damage of some file or of the file system where the persistence is stored. If that happened, it is probably best to create a new persistent live system. You may be able to reuse (keep) the home directory (via a backup). Please be aware, that a persistent live system is rather sensitive to corruption, so it is a good idea to take frequent backups.

Comment: After I went through the menu on the disappearing and reappearing window, I couldn't shut it off. I eventually had to shut down completely wrong. Oh well. At least all that's really wrong is that I have to reinstall some programs

Comment: Can you put your create a new persistence life system as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the action to shutdown/reboot, when the screen was black, caused a damage of some file or of the file system where the persistence is stored.

If that happened, **it is probably best to create a new persistent live system**. You may be able to reuse (keep) the home directory (via a backup)

---

Please be aware, that a persistent live system is rather sensitive to corruption, so it is a good idea to take frequent backups.

The following link describes how [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/) creates a persistent live drive. Near the end [of the linked web page] **backup** of the whole `casper-rw` partition and of the `/home` directory is described.

Note:
Mac users tend to use Mac Linux Usb Loader to create Live USBs, but that program only has options to create persistence, not to repair it.

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

If you use a different method or tool the create your persistent live drive, you can do something similar to backup your system.

Comment: @813bruce, Thanks for the note! I guess you have to do the backup manually, Once you know how to do it, you can create a shellscript, so that it will be convenient in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution.

Creating new persistance in Mac Linux USB Loader did not change the display issue.

However, booting with a different USB fix the problem for my original USB. This time it was a 17.10 Live USB.

Unfortunately, it was after I redid the persistence so I lost all my settings.

- I booted the other USB
- I shut down
- I booted my original live USB

This somehow fixed everything.